# Accessiblity service doesn't see overlay

Tags: android, overlay, accessibilityservice

So I am using `Accessiblity Service` to scan my phones screen to detect overlays and such. The problem I am having is that it doesn't find the view of the pop up, it always scans the text under the overlay, how can I make sure it only scans the current top overlay? So for example I have `testapp` and `testappone`, `testapp` is the current activity and `testappone` is the overlay, when the overlay pops up on top of `testapp` I don't see the data for `testappone` I see the data for `testapp` even though I can see everything on `testappone` above `testapp`.

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event)
{
    final String appPackageName = event.getPackageName().toString();

    if (appPackageName.equals("testappone")){
        AccessibilityNodeInfo source = getRootInActiveWindow();

        processEvent(source);
    }
}

private void processEvent(AccessibilityNodeInfo source){
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   processSubEvent(source, 0, sb);
   String string = sb.toString();

   Log.e(TAG, "String " + string);
}

private void processSubEvent(final AccessibilityNodeInfo source, final int n, final StringBuilder sb){

   sb.append(tools.getText(source));
   sb.append("\n");

   int childCount = source.getChildCount();
   for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
   {
       AccessibilityNodeInfo child = source.getChild(i);

       if (child != null)
       {
           processSubEvent(child, n + 1, sb);
       }

     child.recycle();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessibility services can only see windows that the user can interact with. Non-touchable windows aren't reported to them.

Comment: The windows I am trying to capture have buttons on them I can touch, so it is a touchable window.